# Is there a better way to add optional values to an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, react-native

Currently I'm doing the optional addition using something like this

```
  ...(!!providerId && { providerId }),
  ...(!!practiceId && { practiceId }),
```

Is there some shorthand logic to replace this logic in a graceful manner like

```
 yield createRemarkRequest.post(PATIENT_REMARK, {
  patientId,
  ?providerId,
  ?practiceId,
  noteTypeCode,
  note,
})
```

Comment: We need more context.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is fine (assuming you don't need to include `0` or `""`, etc.; if you do, you'll want something other than a `!!` check). It relies on the fact there aren't any own, enumerable properties on `Boolean` objects, but that's okay, there aren't. :-) I've definitely done that in some code, though not frequently.

But it might be clearer just to make it explicit:

```
const appropriateNameHere = {
    patientId,
    noteTypeCode,
    note,
};
if (providerId) {
    appropriateNameHere.providerId = providerId;
}
if (practiceId) {
    appropriateNameHere.practiceId = practiceId;
}
yield createRemarkRequest.post(PATIENT_REMARK, appropriateNameHere);
```

(That also makes debugging a bit easier.)

Or if `createRemarkRequest.post` ignores `undefined` property values, you could do:

```
yield createRemarkRequest.post(PATIENT_REMARK, {
    patientId,
    providerId: providerId ? providerId : undefined,
    practiceId: practiceId ? practiceId : undefined,
    noteTypeCode,
    note,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The key would be to use variable || undefined

```
yield createRemarkRequest.post(PATIENT_REMARK, {
  patientId,
  providerId: providerId || undefined,
  practiceId: practiceId || undefined,
  noteTypeCode,
  note,
})
```

Be care, that conditional doesn't work with empty arrays or empty objects as a value.
Example:

```
const resultValueOption3 = {
    propZero: propZero || undefined,
    propNull: propNull || undefined,
    propEmptyArray: propEmptyArray || undefined,
    propEmptyObject: propEmptyObject || undefined,
    propEmptyString: propEmptyString || undefined,
    propFalse: propFalse || undefined,
    propTrue: propTrue || undefined,
  };

result: {"propEmptyArray":[],"propEmptyObject":{},"propTrue":true}
```

Finally, I write the whole code with multiple combinations and the results:

```
export function Question11() {

  const propZero = 0;
  const propNull = null;
  const propEmptyArray = [];
  const propEmptyObject = {};
  const propEmptyString = "";
  const propFalse = false;
  const propTrue = true;

  const resultValueOption1 = {
    propZero: propZero ?? null,
    propNull: propNull ?? null,
    propEmptyArray: propEmptyArray ?? null,
    propEmptyObject: propEmptyObject ?? null,
    propEmptyString: propEmptyString ?? null,
    propFalse: propFalse ?? null,
    propTrue: propTrue ?? null,
  };

  const resultValueOption2 = {
    propZero: propZero ?? undefined,
    propNull: propNull ?? undefined,
    propEmptyArray: propEmptyArray ?? undefined,
    propEmptyObject: propEmptyObject ?? undefined,
    propEmptyString: propEmptyString ?? undefined,
    propFalse: propFalse ?? undefined,
    propTrue: propTrue ?? undefined,
  };

  const resultValueOption3 = {
    propZero: propZero || undefined,
    propNull: propNull || undefined,
    propEmptyArray: propEmptyArray || undefined,
    propEmptyObject: propEmptyObject || undefined,
    propEmptyString: propEmptyString || undefined,
    propFalse: propFalse || undefined,
    propTrue: propTrue || undefined,
  };

  const resultValueOption4 = {
    propZero: propZero || null,
    propNull: propNull || null,
    propEmptyArray: propEmptyArray || null,
    propEmptyObject: propEmptyObject || null,
    propEmptyString: propEmptyString || null,
    propFalse: propFalse || null,
    propTrue: propTrue || null,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Option1</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(resultValueOption1)}</div>
      <div>Option2</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(resultValueOption2)}</div>
      <div>Option3</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(resultValueOption3)}</div>
      <div>Option4</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(resultValueOption4)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

/*
  results:
    Option1
     {"propZero":0,"propNull":null,"propEmptyArray":[],"propEmptyObject":{},"propEmptyString":"","propFalse":false,"propTrue":true}
    Option2
     {"propZero":0,"propEmptyArray":[],"propEmptyObject":{},"propEmptyString":"","propFalse":false,"propTrue":true}
    Option3
     {"propEmptyArray":[],"propEmptyObject":{},"propTrue":true}
    Option4
     {"propZero":null,"propNull":null,"propEmptyArray":[],"propEmptyObject":{},"propEmptyString":null,"propFalse":null,"propTrue":true}
*/
```

I hope I've helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a builder function (in another file so you can import it wherever you need it) that handle the case of undefined properties

```
// That's a long name but you get the point
function buildObjectWithoutUndefinedValues(object) {
 return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(objet).filter(([_, value]) => value!== undefined)
  );
}
```

You then just have to call it like this

```
const myObject = buildObjectWithoutUndefinedValues({patientId, providerId // etc...})
```

Answer (score -1):

There is [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) in JavaScript.

You can call your function like below

```
yield createRemarkRequest.post(PATIENT_REMARK, {
  patientId,
  providerId??null, //null or whatever value you want to pass
  practiceId??null,
  noteTypeCode,
  note,
})
```

Comment: But using this we'd still pass the property right? I was looking for a way to skip it

Comment: Can you clarify your question with what you actually want